# Going from plane with texture to cylinder

Tags: modeling, modifiers, objects

I am wondering how to go from a plane with some depth/texture to a cylinder. It is easier for me to design on a flat plane but the eventual shape I want is a cylinder.

[image]

I saw the [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135642/can-i-unwarp-a-cylinder-to-flat-plane-object) going from a flat plane to a cylinder, however it does not work for me because my plane has depth and texture.

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried the Simple Deform modifier (Bend mode)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having Depth and Texture won't prevent the method you tried from working. It's just a matter of setup:

- Make sure all your object scales are applied using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> before doing anything;
- Make sure your meshes have enough geometry to deform appropriately to a
  cylinder;
- Make sure to place the empty either at the very top or at the very bottom of you plane shape, it will make it easier to deform from there rather than the middle;
- Make sure to copy the modifiers on all the objects you need to deform;
- Make sure the meshes all end at the same place, so that they meet at the same place once folded. If you have an object slightly shorter but you don't want to move anything visual, you can duplicate single vertices and use those as invisible endpoint markers.